# How to select rows that contains keywords?

Tags: sql

my_table

```
id  name
1   Sam
4   Ben
7   Amy
8   Samantha
```

I want to search records with name that contains `Sa`.

My query is

```
select * from my_table where 'Sa' like '%name%'
```

but no results are returned

What is the correct query?

Comment: In this case, you have to supply a column to the where clause (name). Then the pattern that the column should contain (%Sa%). So the sql would be:
select * from name where name like %Sa%

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with

```
select * from my_table where name like '%sa%'
```

Answer (score 2):

You are query is searching for text 'name' in column 'Sa' this should be reversed as below

select * from my_table where name like '%Sa%'

Comment: That is not quite correct. `'Sa'` is not a column name, but a string constant, as can be seen from the single quotes. So OP's query actually checks whether the string `'Sa' ` contains the string `'name'`. This also explains why the DBMS doesn't complain that there is no column called `sa` in the table; it doesn't look for one (while `where Sa like '%name%'` would have raised an error).

Answer (score 1):

I thought I'd just add an answer explaining the issue, as some upvoted answers lack any explanation or even got it wrong.

Single quotes in SQL denote string literals (string constants). So

```
where 'Sa' like '%name%'
```

asks whether the string 'Sa'  contains the string 'name', which is not the case, so the query returns no rows.

Unfortunately some DBMS are not strict about delimiters and allow something like the following without raising an error:

```
select 1 as 'myalias'
```

In MySQL (even in the current version 8) you can do this:

```
select 1 as 'myalias'
union all
select 3 as 'myalias' 
union all
select 2 as 'myalias' 
order by 'myalias';
```

And get an unordered result. Why is this? Because while not complaining about `as 'myalias'` as it should, MySQL correctly interprets `order by 'myalias'` as ordering by the string constant 'myalias' which is the same for all rows, so no sorting takes place.

Conclusion: be very careful with delimiters. Single quotes are for string literals. For names we usually don't need delimiters, so `as myalias` is valid. If the alias or name contains special characters like blanks or equals a reserved SQL word, however, you need delimiters. That is double quotes in standard SQL (e.g. `as "my alias"`), but some DBMS use backticks or brackets instead. I suggest you avoid such names completely. You can use the underscore to get readable names without the need for delimiters, e.g. `as my_alias`.

SQL's `LIKE` compares a string (on the left-hand side) with a pattern string (on the right-hand side):

```
some_string LIKE some_pattern
```

Both can be columns, expressions or string constants. Most often we want the content in a column to match a constant pattern. In your case:

```
where name like '%Sa%'
```

Be aware, though, that it depends on the DBMS and collation whether `LIKE` is case sensitive. So in some DBMS with certain character sets above may match the name `'Elsa'`, too, in spite of the lower-case `s`. See your DBMS's docs on this.

The upper-case 'S' in 'Sa' suggests that you are looking for names starting with 'Sa'. In that case you may want to look for the pattern `'Sa%'` rather than `'%Sa%'`. But that wouldn't find `'Uncle Sam'`, because this string doesn't start with 'Sa'. Make your mind up, which of the two patterns you want.

Answer (score 0):

use string value inside single quote not column

```
select * from my_table where  name  like '%Sa%'
```

your searching value will be inside single quote with % and `column` will be after `where`

Comment: OP wants to search the _name column_ for _Sa contents_.

Comment: Please add some explanation to that query - why do you think that it solves the problem? Keep in mind that the OP should be able to learn from your answer

Answer (score 0):

Your column name is in quotes which shouldn't work and By general convention,
we use column name on the left side of the condition after `where` clause. You have rather made your own query complex and in spotlight to be worked on.

```
   select * from my_table 
      where name    --column_names
      like
    '%Sa%'              -- your expression
```